# How can i concatenate the following css string in php without creating another variable or breaking the string?

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code:

```
$el = "<div style='padding: $padding'></div>";
```

The problem is i cannot write

```
$el = "<div style='padding: $paddingpx'></div>";
```

because $paddingpx would then be another variable.

And this will produce a wrong css value

```
$el = "<div style='padding: $padding px'></div>";
```

because if $padding = 20 then '20 px' is wrong and should be '20px'.

How do i concatenate 'px' to the above code. Note that the variable $padding is a value that i will receive from the $_POST action. I would like to know how i can concatenate 'px' with the padding style value without creating any further lines of code of breaking the string like so.

```
$el = "<div style='padding: $padding"."px".'></div>";
```

Thank you, MMK.

Comment: `$el = "<div style='padding: {$padding}px'></div>";`

Comment: The whole purpose of this question is to address the concatenation problem and put everything in a single line of code without breaking the string. And the answer to it is curly braces around the PHP variable like so "<div style='padding: {$padding}px'></div>"; Thank you all. MMK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a curly brace like

```
$el = "<div style='padding: {$padding}px'></div>";
```

Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$el = "<div style='padding: {$padding}px'></div>";
```

Comment: @Eugen Is not copy paste man, is the easiest way to do it. You don't invent PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$el = "<div style='padding: ".$padding."px'></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works as well.
There is some ways to using php code in other php string that contents are html.

```
$el = "<div style='padding: ".$padding."px'></div>";
```